# How do I import a python file into another python file where both files do not have classes and are under the same directory?

Tags: python, importerror

I have 3 files inside the same folder:

1. qrcodeTest.py
2. Data.py
3. Tray.py

They're all under the folder called "Project". Only `Tray.py` has a class called "Tray" but the other 2 files do not contain classes. I am trying to run `qrcodeTest.py` but I need to import Data and Tray (this previously worked when I had all these files under the same folder and ran it in Pycharm).

Inside my `qrcodeTest.py` file, I used to have the following import statements `import Data` and `import Tray` but now these lead to an import error. How do I properly import the Data and Tray files inside `qrcodeTest`?
My files `Data` and `Tray` do not contain functions.

[Edit 1] I have included a screenshot of the error shown in VSCode
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Just to be clear, whether the modules contain class definitions or not is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your code, right?

The import error was not true.

I can reproduce your problem, but I am not sure the import error you met was prompted by `Pylance` like me.

If it is, you can add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/[some paths]/Project",
  ],
```

If it is not, please let me know.

**Update:**

`File > Preferences > Settings` Or shortcut `Ctrl+,` to open the settings.json file. And then click here to open the json file:

[image]

If you open the `qrcodeTest.py` file directly in the VSCode, you should add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Users/zacha/ZCFTest",
  ],
```

If you open the `ZCFTest` folder in the VSCode, you need not configure anything.

`"python.analysis.extraPaths"` means `Addtional import search resolution path`

> Pylance needs to know which import resolution paths to use. By
> default, it uses the root of your workspace. You will need to add
> these additional paths using the "python.analysis.extraPaths" setting
> like this: "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["base", "utils", "dataset",
> ""] Note that these paths are relative to your workspace root
> directory.

From the developer [explain](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/29#issuecomment-653898833).

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, I have added a photo. Perhaps you can take a look

Comment: Also, where can I get the settings.json file? Must I create the file?

Comment: @Zachary Could you have a look into the update?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Data.py
A=10

#Tray.py
B=20

#qrTestCode.py
import Data
import Tray
print(Data.A, Tray.B)
```

Assuming you are using Python 3.x, It should be straightforward.

Comment: Python 3.3+ has Implicit Namespace Packages that allow it to create a packages without an __init__.py file. Which python version are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using python 3.7